# perl's rmtree() failing to delete directory on win32, successful on second try

Tags: windows, perl

In Perl, I do a:

```
rmtree($myfolder);
```

Often this fails on windows. When ran again, it then succeeds. It seems like somehow it takes a while to delete the files in the folder, and somehow it tries to delete the folder before the files are gone.

Is there a "this one actually works" Perl method to erase an directory with all its contents on Windows?

Comment: There's no built-in `rmtree` in Perl. Are you using the `rmtree` function from File::Path, or some other `rmtree`?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a virus scanner running?  If it's scanning a file, it has the file open.  Windows won't let you delete files/directories that are open by another process.

Answer (score 2):

@OP, whenever things happen, always check whether you can handle those errors. See [perldoc File::Path](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Path.html). Under remove_tree(), you can use `verbose` and `error => \$err` to show you errors encountered.

Answer (score 2):

I took over and greatly improved [File::Remove](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Remove) a while back, which is a bit more extreme and paranoid about deleting things.

It might do what you want.

And if it doesn't let me know and I'll improve it.